# How to get rid off delay after changing activity?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-activity

I am writing app to control Windows mouse/keyboard via java class Robot. App is using Sockets. Server in java and client in android java. Currently I have all working but I have problem with performance. My app look like:
MainMenu which shows list -> chose keyboard, chose mouse. Let's say I chosen to use mouse first and it works fine. Then I click back button on my phone and go to keyboard and now I have slower performance(little delay). When i go  back to mouse I have delay as well which really hurts.
I am passing/sharing objects of my connection through GlobalClass. 
So the question is how to minimize/fix those delays?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some code... Is the PC and Mobile on the same network? It's not a network latency problem?

Comment: yes they are on the same network. It doesn't looks like latency problem. Which part of code do you need?

Comment: Your description is far too vague to be answered sensibly. How much is "slower performance"? 10 seconds or 10 milliseconds? Is the delay in the app or in the network? How much data are you passing between the activities? Without seeing the code (and a lot more *specific* info), it's really hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are leaving the connections/sockets open.

So your first usage, you connect once. Then the second usage, you have two connections then three and so on.

Most likely sending extra data down the sockets, causing a slow in network performance.

The simple solution to this is.. When you exit your activity (pressing back to go to MainMenu), make sure you close ALL connections you opened in the activity.

So for example in your `OnCreate()` method you have opened a socket..
make sure in your `OnDestroy()` method, you are closing it!

You should probably also take into account the fact that they might close your app with the menu button. (to be reopened later). 
So you should really release the sockets in `OnPause()` and start/restart the socket in `OnResume()` , rather than create and destroy methods.

Comment: NO, I have 1 global variable with connection Object,So i dont want to close and reopen sockets all the time

Comment: @PatrykGurgul Without any code, there is no way I am supposed to have known that. Please provide code in your question so that someone can answer it better.